# How to find strings in certain html tags and cut off these tags from result using regular expressions?

Tags: html, regex

I need to find some strings inside HTML-page. So the page contains this fragment:

```
<div class="member">
    <span>
        <strong>Mr.</strong>
    </span>
    <span>
       <strong>Name</strong>
    </span>
    <span>
       <strong>Surname</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

And this is not the full code of page of cource. I need to extract a string `Mr. Name Surname` using regex only.

So if I'll use `<strong>[\w.]*</strong>`, it will find:

```
[0] : <strong>Mr.</strong>
[1] : <strong>Name</strong>
[2] : <strong>Surname</strong>
```

Here are 3 problems.

1) Result contains strings with tags, I need to exclude tags from result.

2) Regex could find all `<strong>` entries on the page, not only inside this div.

3) I should to concatenate these strings like this `Mr. Name Surname`. Is it possible to use regular expressions only?

How to fix my expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Instead of operating on the HTML as if it were plain text, consider using an HTML parsing library. For example, Python's BeautifulSoup. Then you can do something like `document.getElementsByClassName("member")[0].getElementsByTagName("strong")` instead of messing with regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
First of all, I get the whole content of this div like this:

```
/(?<=<div\sclass\=\"member\">)([\s\S]*)(?=<\/div>)/gmi
```

So, now I have:

```
<span>
    <strong>Mr.</strong>
</span>
<span>
   <strong>Name</strong>
</span>
<span>
   <strong>Surname</strong>
</span>
```

Then I just remove all tags, excess spaces and linebreaks:

```
$out0 = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($inputstr)));
```

where `$inputstr` is my div content.

This way isn't universal, but it solved my problem.